# Redirect Method take too long in Diem symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4, diem-cms

I am using `$this->redirect($redirection)` where $redirection is a `$this->getRouteArrayForAction('index')`.

But It take too long time like 180ms but if I use php core method like `header('Location: ' . $redirection);`

it take like 4-12 ms. I can't figure out what is going on?

I am using Diem Symfony 1.4.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are  you using?  What does it say in the Timers section of you  Web Dev Toolbar?

Comment: Linux and using chrome page load time addon

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I never used header redirects in symfony.  There is too much going on before it gets to the action level.

If page load time is an issue I would take a look at using session storage in the database.  I saw some complaints about session handling on the google diem-user board.

http://www.designdisclosure.com/2009/11/symfony-doctrine-database-session-storage/

It may also be a question of whether you are in dev or production, since templates are regenerated in dev.